# how to use classes in python

Tags: python, class

I have a list of book and and a list of ratings for the book from users.

[User1,2,1,3,6]..
[User2,4,1,4 2]..

[Book1,Book2,Book3,Book4]
ratings from(1-4)

example
if Book 1 is "The Pope" 
the raitings for the the book are [3,3,3,2]
the print out is 
         The Pope [3,3,3,2] [ ]

using a class

here is the set up for my class.

```
class Book(object):
      booktotal=0
      accept=[]
      def __init__(self, Title= " ", Rating=()):
          self.scale=[1,2,3,4]
          self.book = Title
          self.rating= Rating
          self.accept=[]
          book.population +=1
      def AddRating(self,rating):
          if rating in self.scale:
              accepted.append(rating)
          else:
              pass

          return self.accept

      def Average(self):
          Avg=sum[accept]/3

      def __str__(self):
          return '{0} - {1} - {2}'.format(self.book, self.rating,self.accept)
```

how do i get it to print out the average and the number of reviews

Comment: Format your code correctly (python cares about indentation), and observe PEP 8 conventions http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/. In addition, tell us what is currently wrong with your code, and show some input and output demonstrating that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have can be cut down significantly.

- `population` isn't defined anywhere. So that's an error.
- Your average calculation is wrong. It only really needs to be calculated in the `__str__` method.
- Use the `len` function to get the number of elements in a list.

  ```
  class Book(object):               
    scale=(1,5)

    def __init__(self, title):        
        self.title = title
        self.ratings = []

    def rate(self,rating):
        if rating in range(self.scale[0]-1, self.scale[1]+1):
            self.ratings.append(rating)

    def __str__(self):
        return '"{0}" rates an average of {1} from {2} reviews.'.format(
           self.title, sum(self.ratings)/float(len(self.ratings)), len(self.ratings))

  >> mybook = Book('Zen of Python')
  >> mybook.rate(5)
  >> mybook.rate(3)
  >> mybook.rate(5)
  >> str(mybook)
  >> "Zen of Python" rate an average of 4.333333333 from 3 reviews.
  ```

Comment: Note that putting `ratings` as a class variable is probably a bad idea. That will make it shared between all books (much like a `static` variable in C++ or Java). Instead you should create it in the `__init__` method, so it belongs to a specific instance. (The `scale` variable is probably fine, since it is intended to be used only as a constant. However, you could improve the check to be `if self.scale[0] <= rating <= self.scale[1]` or even abandon the tuple in favor of two variables with better names, such as `min_rating`/`max_rating`.)

Comment: You're right, I made the changes regarding the class variable. As for the range, there is definitely many ways to implement it, that's just the way I decided to.